# How to populate data in dashing dashboard

Tags: ruby, jobs, dashing

I have created a dashboard using us map widgets in dashing using following git link:

https://gist.github.com/jrunge/acd98d3d550911bdc4b5

Can anybody tell me how to create the custom job to populate data to be sent to widget? The JSON data follows this format

```
{
  "points": [
    {
      "id": 12345,
      "lat": 35,
      "lon": -70,
      "type": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": 678910,
      "lat": 35,
      "lon": -70,
      "type": "green"
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I need to create a shell script or command to populate the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a ruby script in `jobs` directory
**jobs/us-map.rb**

```
SCHEDULER.every '2s' do
  us_map_details = {
    "points": [
      {
        "id": 12345,
        "lat": 35,
        "lon": -70,
        "type": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": 678910,
        "lat": 35,
        "lon": -70,
        "type": "green"
      }
    ]
  }
  # You can change the hash us_map_details to add/change/remove points
  another_point = {"id": 1729, "lat": 30, "lon": -60, "type": "red" }
  us_map_details[:points] << another_point

  send_event('usmap', us_map_details) # This is where data is sent to dashboard
end
```

The `SCHEDULER` object is an instance of [rufus scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). You can populate data by populating `us_map_details` hash

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to populate a widget.

first is the Scheduler job. You can create one with the command

```
dashing generate job [Name_Of_Job]
```

Secondly, you can send data to the widget by using the `curl` command:

```
curl -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "text": "Hey, Look what I can do!" }' http://<%=request.host%>:<%=request.port%>/widgets/welcome
```